# .CSVT File no longer converting string variable to float value

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I was testing joining a dataset to shapefiles in Qgis. The text file that I used in my earlier testing as my csvt file worked perfectly and I was able to create gradient maps using my joined dataset. However, I have now moved the exact same dataset and the exact same csvt file over to another map in a different project. I joined the dataset to this map in exactly the same way with the csvt file in the same folder, just as before, but I am no longer able to create gradients using the data from the dataset. Specifically when I try to select the column to use for the gradient it should (and did) list 22 different variable options which are floats, now it does not list any as options. I have not changed anything in the text file, nor the dataset, so I have been unable to figure out why this worked fine earlier and no longer does.

[image: Screen shot of Qgis project and csvt text file]

Answer (score 1):

Your csvt is not working because it does have a txt extension also (see your attached image) . In windows explorer activate view file extensions and erase the .txt. That should work